# Elegantly creating a hash from an array

Tags: ruby

I currently have some Ruby code that creates output like this (after conversion to JSON):

```
"days": [
    {
        "Jul-22": ""
    },
    {
        "Aug-19": ""
    }
],
```

What I want is output like this:

```
"days": {
    "Jul-22": "",
    "Aug-19": ""
},
```

Here is my code:

```
CalendarDay.in_the_past_30_days(patient).select(&:noteworthy?).collect do |noteworthy_day|
  { noteworthy_day.date.to_s(:trends_id) => "" }
end
```

In other words I want a hash instead of an array of hashes. Here's my ugly solution:

```
days = {}
CalendarDay.in_the_past_30_days(patient).select(&:noteworthy?).each do |noteworthy_day|
  days[noteworthy_day.date.to_s(:trends_id)] = ""
end 
days
```

That seems very unrubylike, though. Can someone help me do this more efficiently?

Comment: You actually have a hash of hashes

Comment: this question would be better suited to the [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) since your focus is style, not functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hash[
  CalendarDay.in_the_past_30_days(patient).select(&:noteworthy?).collect { |noteworthy_day|
    [noteworthy_day.date.to_s(:trends_id), ""]
  }
]
```

Or...

```
CalendarDay.in_the_past_30_days(patient).select(&:noteworthy?).each_with_object(Hash.new) { |noteworthy_day, ndays|
  ndays[noteworthy_day] = ""
}
```

Comment: I used the first one. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonSwett Cool. Ruby prides itself in many (good and reasonable) ways of doing the same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem tailor made for [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
CalendarDay.in_the_past_30_days(patient).select(&:noteworthy?).inject({}) do |hash, noteworthy_day|
    hash[noteworthy_day.date.to_s(:trends_id)] = ''
    hash
end
```